# prepareForSegue not sending parameters when called, resulting in a crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have two segues going out of my initial view controller.  The push segue is connected to the cell and the modal is connected to the + UIBarButtonItem.

[image]

When this is what my prepareForSegue code looks like, everything is fine and filePath is sent through the push segue, but the filePath isn't passed through the modal segue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showTimes"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setFilePath:filePath];
    }

//    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addEvent"]) {
//        [[segue destinationViewController] setFilePath:filePath];
//    } 
}
```

If I uncomment the second if statement and segue identifier, the app crashes.  filePath is sent nowhere.  I've tried moving `[[segue destinationViewController] setFilePath:filePath];` out of both if statements in an attempt to ensure that that line was executed, but that also crashes my app.

Both segues have the correct identifiers set up in the Attributes.  However, I'm not sure that Xcode is actually realizing that the correct identifiers are set up because when I change the segue types, those changes aren't reflected the next time I run the app.

I'm a loss for what to do.  I'm relatively new to Objective-C.

Comment: replace second if with else if

Comment: I've tried `else if` too, but it gives the same result as when it's commented out.  I've tried changing it to `else` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Check answer of Jason Coco below, if that does not works,please share the crash reason displayed in the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addEvent` segue points to a navigation controller, not your view controller. Instead, get your view controller and set the file path on that:

```
[[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController] setFilePath:filePath];
```

Comment: Now the compiler has a problem with setFilePath: and says "No visible @interface for 'UiViewController' declares the selector 'setFilePath:'.  I have the destination view controller imported and filePath is declared in each .h file.  What does that mean?

Comment: You'll have to cast the UIViewController to your specific subclass for the compiler to know about the -setFilePath method. ie, `[(SubclassName*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController] setFilePath:filePath];`

Comment: Of course having one class presume to know the type of the destinationViewController is not exactly loosely coupled... Using a delegate protocol between them would be more standard. You would set the destination as the source's delegate, then call the delegate method passing your filePath in as a parameter, and THEN perform the segue.

Comment: Thank you!!  Casting the UIViewController worked, but I'll have to read more about delegation so that I can implement the more standard protocol.